# How to set/update expiration time for a table in Google big Query using ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-bigquery

I am using google-cloud-bigquery gem for my Ruby on Rails application. I am able to execute the query on the dataset and do the following

1. Execute query
2. Create destination table and store results into it
3. Store the final results into a file from a destination table

Now I want to set the expiration time for the destination table. I find a document to [updating a table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-tables#updating_a_tables_expiration_time). But I am unable to find a way to set the expiration time using Ruby language?

Also I am able to fetch [expires_at](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/master/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/table.rb#L703) value from a table which returns nil. I don't find a way to set it.

Kindly help

Comment: Did you try taking a look in this doc? https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-bigquery/latest/Google/Cloud/Bigquery/Table.html#time_partitioning_expiration=-instance_method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm no Ruby expert, but I also cannot find anything in the docs/api that allows you to set the expiration on a table. You can do it at the dataset level ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/36e4550e61d8eb0501f913fd30111093d6257aae/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/dataset.rb#L226)) or for partitions on the table ([here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/blob/36e4550e61d8eb0501f913fd30111093d6257aae/google-cloud-bigquery/lib/google/cloud/bigquery/table.rb#L403)). It looks like it's not exposed via the client library for some reason.

Another way of doing it is via [DDL in SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#table_set_options_list) e.g:

```
ALTER TABLE mydataset.mytable
 SET OPTIONS (
   expiration_timestamp=TIMESTAMP_ADD(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 DAY),
   description="Table that expires seven days from now"
 )
```